# How to show data from database in Data List Control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a project in which I am working on admin interface . In admin interface I have to do following work.

- Allow user to select table in which
  he want to perform
  action(delte,show,update).
- While saving user information. i am
  saving the image path. and i have to
  also so a user image in admin
  interface in respect to userid.

The problem is that I have save image path. and i have to show image in data list control. Can any one suggest how can I perform this task? I have to use data list through source code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I understand you corectly you want a dropdown of images which is, to the best of my knowledge, impossible.
What you could do is create a databound drop-down and and image controll which will display the image selected in the dropdown, as such:

```
    SqlDataSource yourDataSource = new SqlDataSource("your connection string here", "select command here. Something like 'SELECT id, image FROM table'");
    DropDownList yourDropDown = new DropDownList();
    yourDropDown.DataSource = yourDataSource;
    // makes the dropdown show the id but the value will return the image value
    yourDropDown.DataTextField = "id";
    yourDropDown.DataValueField = "image";
    yourDropDown.DataBind();

    Image img = new Image();
    img.ImageUrl = yourDropDown.SelectedValue;
```

then you could update the ImageURL property OnIndexChanged.

Best of luck,
              Michael